# AntiForgeryToken Asp Net Core рандомно пересоздается, как исправить?

Tags: аутентификация, авторизация

Проблема заключается в том, что при Авторизации и Аутентификации на сайте через хостинг(reg.ru), сервер Plesk(IIS), ASP NET CORE - периодически пересоздается AntiForgeryToken, Особенно после POST запросов, но и без таковых также пересоздается новый токен(только реже).

Соответственно Аутентификация сбрасывается и приходится переавторизовываться.

Если удалить токен, то создается токен с тем же Value, но с другим Expires/Max-Age , то есть не выкидывает с авторизации.

Данной проблемы не наблюдается при тестировании на localhost.

Из того что используется на сайте:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => {
        options.Cookie.Name = "AUTHCOOKIE";
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Также изменил AntiForgeryToken:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "ANTIFORGERY-SHVEDOVA";
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(3650);
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryShvedovaAV";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-SHVEDOVAAV-NAME";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});
```

Аутентификация происходит так:

```
HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimsPrincipal);
```

Заранее спасибо, и извиняюсь если что не так описал...(первый раз)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Сброс AntiforgeryToken был из-за превышения лимита памяти текущего тарифа на хостинге. Сообщение из лога:

> 02.07.2022 0:30:51  A worker process with process id of '244048' serving application pool 'u1567816.plsk.regruhosting.ru(domain)(4.0)(pool)' has requested a recycle because it reached its virtual memory limit.

Чтобы избежать данного инцидента, нужно повысить лимит, либо снизить нагрузку на сервер.